# Find highest transaction amount after any canceled transaction

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table containing millions of transactions. I need to find the highest paid current amount. "Current" is defined as occurring *after* the last canceled transaction. The table is as follows:

```
Id (guid)    ServiceId   CreatedDate               AmountPaid    InsurerId   IsCanceled
76E9A3...    19          2013-08-30 12:34:01.580   56.00         96          0
C3F325...    19          2013-08-30 12:34:02.069   14.95         110         0
96E9A3...    19          2013-08-30 12:32:01.540   109.00        95          1
C3BC25...    19          2013-08-30 12:32:02.007   15.95         108         1
85E9A3...    19          2013-08-30 12:30:01.701   101.00        95          0
A3F325...    19          2013-08-30 12:30:02.069   13.95         108         0
```

As you can see, for the same serviceID, I have multiple transactions. What I need to retrieve here is the $56 transaction, because it is the highest for that ServiceId *after* the most recent canceled transaction for that same ServiceID.

If I do:

```
 ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC, AmountPaid DESC
```

The 1st row would be the 14.95$ transaction...

If I do:

```
ORDER BY AmountPaid DESC, CreatedDate DESC
```

The 1st row would be the 101$ transaction

MORE INFO:

Once a service transaction is canceled, any transaction become invalid. The only transactions valid are the one(s) created after the canceled transactions.

Comment: So why shouldn't it be the 101$ transaction anyway? How do you define recent enough?

Comment: Is 56 higher than 109 and 101?

Comment: I added some extra information.

Comment: What you need to add is how to compute "Most Recent and Highest Amount". The 2nd row is more recent than the first, so that will appear. Is there an interval in which transactions should be considered as having happened at the same time? What is the exact logic that means that $14.95 is the one you need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
;WITH m AS
(
  SELECT ServiceID, m = MAX(CreatedDate) 
  FROM dbo.whatever 
  WHERE IsCanceled = 1 GROUP BY ServiceID
),
n AS
(
  SELECT w.*, 
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY w.ServiceID ORDER BY w.AmountPaid DESC)
  FROM dbo.whatever AS w
  LEFT OUTER JOIN m ON w.ServiceID = m.ServiceID
  WHERE w.CreatedDate > COALESCE(m.m, '19000101')
)
SELECT * FROM n WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) and a [`CTE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT t1.Id, t1.ServiceId, t1.CreatedDate, t1.AmountPaid,  t1.InsurerId, t1.IsCanceled,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY t1.ServiceId
                                 ORDER BY t1.AmountPaid DESC, t1.CreatedDate DESC )
    FROM dbo.Transactions t1
    WHERE  t1.iscanceled = 0 
    AND (NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.transactions t2 
                    WHERE  t1.serviceid = t2.serviceid 
                    AND    t2.iscanceled = 1) 
     OR (t1.createddate > (
                   SELECT Max(createddate) 
                   FROM   dbo.transactions t2 
                   WHERE  t1.serviceid = t2.serviceid 
                   AND t2.iscanceled = 1)))
)
SELECT Id, ServiceId, CreatedDate, AmountPaid,  InsurerId, IsCanceled
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a866e/18/0)</kbd>

Comment: This would return the 14.95$ transaction which (for reasons unclear) is not the desired one.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: But OP is interested only in rows where `IsCanceled=0`. According to the desired result, i have just looked at the requirement OP has mentioned, not at the actual data.

Comment: @MartinSmith: I prefer to answer a requirement not possibly wrong sample data or incorrect results.

Comment: The question is very clear that neither `ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC, AmountPaid DESC` nor `ORDER BY AmountPaid DESC, CreatedDate DESC` return the desired results. But less clear on how the desired results are arrived at.

Comment: @MartinSmith: You're right. I've overlooked that he already tried this order. I assume he wants the the highest `AmountPaid` after the last `IsCanceled`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Thanks for pointing that out. Edited my answer to take into account that there are no canceled transactions at all. I assume OP wants then the one with the highest AmountPaid. However, your query is more concise :)

Comment: SSMS is so awesome. [Add up those percentages](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7r6da.png).